# Слово "переобновлён"

Tags: грамотная-речь, словообразование, стилистика

Можно ли употребить слово "переобновлён"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Можно ли употребить слово "переобновлён"?

Не думаю, что это оправдано. Само по себе использование вновь образованных слов с подобными приставками допустимо, если текст не слишком официальный, но здесь сталкиваются две приставки с похожим смыслом. Избыточно. "Об-" и "прере-", конечно, не абсолютные синонимы даже в этом конкретном значении, но в целом получается "перемудрёж". Смотрите. Обновить - сделать что-то новым или заново. А "пере"? Почти тоже самое, ср. переделать.

Таким образом, если речь идет о том, что надо сделать "новое обновление", лучше так и сказать. ***"повторно обновит"***, например. Другие значения "пере" (избыточность, например) я исключаю.

Answer (score 1):

В каком-нибудь подходящем контексте, *иронизируя*, можно себе позволить такое слово; на письме - в кавычках.

> Тот файл был обновлён, да неудачно, ну а теперь он "переобновлён"!

Answer (score 0):

Это слово не фиксируется нормативными словарями (в отличие от *обновить*) и, скорее всего, является просторечным.

Если вы приведете контекст, можно будет дать более конкретный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Мне "переобновлен" напоминает шуточное "распренаипрекраснейший", т.е. слово-то может существовать (построено грамотно), но смысла не имеет. Согласен с behemothus.